# Change permission on the basis of button chosen in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on DRF and using viewsets for creating APIs. Here I am having one problem:
Suppose, I have two buttons in a form i.e. Employee and Manager. If the user clicked on Employee, then it has access to only GET request and if he clicked on Manager, then it has POST, PUT, PATCH permissions.

**models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

**viewsets.py**

```
class EmpViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [OfficeEngineerPermission]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

I tried to write custom permission but it doesn't work.

**custom_permiss.py**

```
SAFE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'HEADER', 'OPTIONS']
class OfficeEngineerPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (request.method in SAFE_METHODS and request.user == 'OfficeEngineer'):
            return True
        return Response({'message':'This is not allowed'})
```

I read all things but getting stuck. Please suggest!

Comment: How do you persist the state of which button the user selected (employee vs manager)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the viewsets `get_permissions()` method and define a permission for each of the viewset actions

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

For example, I did a quick test with the following:

```py
class MyModelViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    model = MyModel

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "create":
            self.permission_classes = [IsNotSuperUser]
        elif self.action == "update":
            self.permission_classes = [IsTeacher]
        elif self.action == "partial_update":
            self.permission_classes = [IsNotSuperUser]
        elif self.action == "list":
            self.permission_classes = [IsSuperUser, IsAuthenticated]
        elif self.action == "retrieve":
            self.permission_classes = [IsSuperUser, IsAuthenticated]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
```

With this you can control permissions for each of the HTTP verbs.